# Moodle - Hook events for customizing core functionality

Tags: listener, hook, moodle

In moodle , is there a way to hook onto core functionality such as adding courses, creating users and adding our own custom code, so there is no core modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are events that trigger after users / courses have been updated, so you can take your own actions after these have taken place.

There isn't a way to override the original functionality, without making core modifications.

For Moodle versions before 2.7, the events API is documented at: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API
(Section 5 has a list of core events you can listen to)

For Moodle 2.7 onwards, the events API is documented at:
http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2
(Section 4.5.1 has a list of core events you can listen to)

Comment: where can i find sample code for using events api, as the above two links do not have it.

Comment: Search the moodle code for any files called db/events.php (e.g in mod_forum), then look at the functions they mention. The first link above gives an example under 'event handling', the second shows some code under 'event observers' (the only bit missing is an example of the actual function that is called).